# Solving Augmented Matrix Breaking Strict Triangle Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations:

$ 3x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 = 0\\
-2x_1 + x_2 -x_3 = 2\\
2x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 = -1
$

From which I'm using the augmented matrix:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      3&2&1&0\\
      -2&1&-1&2\\
      2&-1&2&-1
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction, but I've managed to simplify it initially by manipulating the first row by a constant and combining it with the second row to reduce it, like so:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2&\frac{4}{3}&\frac{2}{3}&0\\
      0&\frac{7}{3}&\frac{-1}{3}&2\\
      2&-1&2&-1
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I also used the same process for the third row:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2&\frac{4}{3}&\frac{2}{3}&0\\
      0&\frac{7}{3}&\frac{-1}{3}&2\\
      0&\frac{7}{3}&\frac{8}{3}&-1
    \end{array}
\right] $$

But I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm trying to achieve strict triangle form, but doing any operations on row 2 and row 3 would create a $0$ entry (in row 2 column 2) that would break such form.

I also happen to know the correct answer to this problem is: $\{-1, 1, 1\}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second manipulation step an error occured. If you subtract $[2 ,-1, 2| -1]$ by $[2, \frac{4}{3}, \frac{2}{3}| 0]$ you obtain $[0, -\frac{7}{3}, \frac{4}{3}|-1]$. Now add the second row to the third row.

Comment: Ah, yes, fixing that solved it. Thank you so much!